# Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Only one entity may be annotated with @RevisionEntity

Tags: hibernate

I tried to use Hibernate Envers to log the entity histroy. but failed.

My project used Spring 3.1, JPA and Spring Data JPA(Hibenrate 4.1).

there is a based class.

Code:

> ```
> @javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass
> public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
>
>
>
>     @Id
>     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
>     @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "INT unsigned", nullable = false)
>     @RevisionNumber
>     public Long id;
>
>
>
>     @Version
>     @Column(name = "jpaversion", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT unsigned")
>    @RevisionTimestamp
>     public Long version;
>
>
>
>     public Long getId() {
>    return id;
>     }
>
>
>
>     public void setId(Long id) {
>    this.id = id;
>     }
>
>
>
>     public Long getVersion() {
>    return version;
>     }
>
>
>
>     public void setVersion(Long version) {
>    this.version = version;
>     }
>
>
>
>     @Override
>     public int hashCode() {
>    final int prime = 31;
>    int result = 1;
>    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
>    return result;
>     }
>
>
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
>    if (this == obj)
>        return true;
>    if (obj == null)
>        return false;
>    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
>        return false;
>    BaseEntity other = (BaseEntity) obj;
>    if (id == null) {
>        if (other.id != null)
>       return false;
>    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
>        return false;
>    return true;
>     }
>
>
>
> }
> ```

When I added @RevisionEntity to my entites.

Code:

> ```
> @Entity
> @RevisionEntity
> @Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = {
>     @UniqueConstraint(name = "UQ_gsmPrefix_gsmNumber", columnNames = {"gsm_prefix", "gsm_number"}),
>     @UniqueConstraint(name = "UQ_email", columnNames = "email"),
>     @UniqueConstraint(name = "UQ_username", columnNames = "username")})
> @NamedQueries({
>     @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUsername", query = "select u from User u where u.username=:username"),
>     @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmail", query = "select u from User u where u.email=:email")})
> @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
> public class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails, Serializable {
> ```

Code:

> @Entity
>       @Table(name = "address")
>       @RevisionEntity
>       public class Address extends com.dna.bifincan.model.BaseEntity

and when I deployed the project into tomcat, I got the exception like this.

Quote:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/E:/MyWorks/bifincan/project/bifincan-website/target/fi/WEB-INF/lib/bifincan-library-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/common/data-access.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: bifincan]
>   Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:530)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1471)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:856)
>       at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:353)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/E:/MyWorks/bifincan/project/bifincan-website/target/fi/WEB-INF/lib/bifincan-library-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/common/data-access.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: bifincan]
>   Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:400)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
>       at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
>       at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:103)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>       ... 50 more
>       Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: bifincan] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
>       ... 65 more
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Only one entity may be annotated with @RevisionEntity!
>       at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.RevisionInfoConfiguration.configure(RevisionInfoConfiguration.java:264)
>       at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.(AuditConfiguration.java:102)
>       at org.hibernate.envers.configuration.AuditConfiguration.getFor(AuditConfiguration.java:165)
>       at org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:64)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:302)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1740)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:88)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
>       ... 71 more

Obviously, I used @Entity and @RevisitonEntity together, but it still report this info.

I read the doc of related section in the Hibernate Dev Guide, it seems there does not need extra configuration in the persistence.xml or hibernate configuration.  Is there something I omitted in the Spring project.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to annotate your entities with `@RevisionEntity`?

`@RevisionEntity` is a special purpose entity that represents the revision itself. If you want to make your entities audited by Envers, annotate them with `@Audited`.